# Does packet table appending use buffering?

Tags: hdf5

Right now I've working with the HDF5 C++ interface to write out entries into a 1d dataset with infinite length. The entries are produced one at a time, but to minimize writes to disk I accumulate an array of entries, and then write them to disk in blocks once the size of the array reaches some threshold. This results in a significant performance gain, but complicates the code quite a lot.

I recently learned about the Packet Table interface, which could potentially streamline things, but the real benefit would be if it buffers the data before writing to disk. I can't tell from the docs whether Packet Tables do this, does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Buffering data by yourself is much faster than writing to packet table directly.

Looking at the implementation (version 1.8.17 and 1.10.0-patch1), it turns out that a single call to of `H5PTappend` has so much work to do in order to write the data:

1. extend dataset according to how many record we are appending
2. create memory data space
3. get a copy of file data space
4. define hyperslab in the dataset
5. call `H5Dwrite` which has lots of work to do on its own

If you are writing small packet (like a single numeric value) one by one, these work would take much more time than time actually spent writing data to disk.

So it's better to buffer your data in this case, but packet table API still makes creating 1d dataset with infinite length much easier. After figuring out the cause for poor performance, this is the reason for me to use packet table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bother doing the buffering by hand. `H5::DataSet::write` (and the underlying `H5Dwrite`) are buffered by default. For special needs, you can control the buffer size using a dataset transfer property list but the default values usually work very well.

I'm not familiar with Packet Table but since it is a high level interface built upon the low level one, it is very likely that the writes are buffered too.

Comment: that's weird, because I noticed a pretty significant speed increase when I buffered the data by hand… what are the default values?